# General Music/Headphone Help

Tags: iphone, ios, music, headphones

*Well, this got put on hold from regular StackExchange for being a general software questing, but I don't know specifics about this. I'm just going to copy and paste my original description. Also, please don't say it's not a good programming question also I don't know if this community is only programming or not. I would like an answer that doesn't require messing with my phones OS too much, but if not, oh well.*

Ok, I'm new to iOS 10, and I was just using 4.4.4 (KitKat). With headphones, on Android, when you would hit the play button, it would play your queue. On iOS, it will shuffle all my music. How can I make it not do this? It only happens when I clear the music app from multitasking, which I accidentally do (ALOT). I have the regular Apple earbuds, and I have the iPhone 7. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** Please don't just downvote. Ask me a question if you don't understand. I know the title doesn't ask a question, but I HAVE NO CLUE HOW TO ASK THIS....

Answer (score 1):

The Music app on iOS can be confusing. For some conceptual help see [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204951) at Apple Support. I find it easier to create Playlists (either on my Phone, or better yet, in iTunes on my Mac,) and and use them instead of playing the entire library.

Here's some guidance from Apple:

**Play your music**

If you want to listen to an artist's entire collection of music that you've saved to your library, find the artist in Library > Artists. Tap Shuffle All [image] to play all of their music.

**Create a playlist**

You can create playlists to listen to or share with friends. From the Library tab, tap Playlists, then New Playlist. Fill in details for your playlist, such as the title and description, then add music. If you like, you can also add an image. When you're happy with your playlist, tap Done in the upper-right corner.
If you don't see Playlists under Library, tap Edit in the upper-right corner, then tap Playlists to turn it on. Tap Done to return to Library.

**Up Next, Shuffle, and Repeat**

Also on the Now Playing screen, you can rewind, pause, or fast forward a song, control the volume, read song lyrics, and more.

Swipe up on Now Playing to show your Up Next queue, which lists all of the songs that you’ve selected for playback.

Drag songs with [image] to rearrange the order, or swipe left to remove a song that you’d like to skip.

Tap [image] Shuffle to shuffle the songs in a playlist or album.

Tap [image] Repeat once to play an entire playlist or album on repeat or twice to repeat one song.

Tap [image] a third time to clear the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS it's dependent on what app you are playing music from. For iTunes/Apple Music open up the Music app and when viewing the now playing card you can swipe up and it will show the controls for shuffle and repeat.

To get to the music now playing card go to Songs > Select a Song > Tap on the Song that appears on the bottom of the screen.